# Get Jenkins failed jobs details

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to see how many jobs are falling in Jenkins at particular time frame. The following script gives me all the failed job. Is there a way i can get failed job based on time?

`activeJobs = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.items.findAll{job -> job.isBuildable()}
failedRuns = activeJobs.findAll{job -> job.lastBuild != null && job.lastBuild.result == hudson.model.Result.FAILURE}
failedRuns.each{run -> println(run.name)}`

Comment: Did my response answer the Q or you need more details?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to get `lfb = job.getLastFailedBuild()` and then test `lfb.getTime()` for your timerange. [JavaDoc reference - Job](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Job.html)